# FPGA BRAM Stack Implementation Xilinx 7-Series

Tags: hardware, vhdl, fpga, xilinx

I am creating a stack based on the artix-7 fabric on the zynq soc. To create the stack I want to use the BRAM, I'm having a problem that the BRAM read output doesn't change, I've used BRAMS many times before (not 7-series so I may be missing something subtle) and am totally perplexed as to why it is doing this.

I filled the stack with values: 1, 2 ,3

When I then call pop successively the only value it reads out is 3 for each pop and read address (even after waiting for the one clock read delay). I have also tried with dual port rams and had the same issue, i'm sticking to single port as it simpler to try and workout what is going wrong!

I have verified the logic behavior using an array based ram which has the correct behavior. For verification I also checked the logic from this source: http://vhdlguru.blogspot.co.uk/2011/01/implementation-of-stack-in-vhdl.html.

So the issue appears to be with the BRAM, either it is not reading properly or for some reason it is writing the value 3 to all previous memory address which makes no sense as each data item is synced with a write signal and correct address.

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use ieee.std_logic_unsigned.all;
use IEEE.numeric_std.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if using
-- arithmetic functions with Signed or Unsigned values
--use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD.ALL;

-- Uncomment the following library declaration if instantiating
-- any Xilinx primitives in this code.
library UNISIM;
use UNISIM.VComponents.all;

-- Stack implementation for 32 bit data items using BRAM componenets
entity stack_32_BRAM is
    generic( ADDR : integer :=32);
    Port ( clk : in  STD_LOGIC;
           rst : in  STD_LOGIC;
           en : in  STD_LOGIC;
           push_pop : in  STD_LOGIC;
           data_in : in  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0);
           data_out : out  STD_LOGIC_VECTOR (31 downto 0));
end stack_32_BRAM;

architecture Behavioral of stack_32_BRAM is

COMPONENT BRAM_32_1K
  PORT (
    clka : IN STD_LOGIC;
    rsta : IN STD_LOGIC;
    wea : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
    addra : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
    dina : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
    douta : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
    clkb : IN STD_LOGIC;
    rstb : IN STD_LOGIC;
    web : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
    addrb : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
    dinb : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
    doutb : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0)
  );
END COMPONENT;

COMPONENT BRAM_32_1K_SP
  PORT (
    clka : IN STD_LOGIC;
    rsta : IN STD_LOGIC;
    wea : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(3 DOWNTO 0);
    addra : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
    dina : IN STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0);
    douta : OUT STD_LOGIC_VECTOR(31 DOWNTO 0)
  );
END COMPONENT;

--The read ptr is a function of the write ptr
signal stack_ptr_read, stack_ptr_write : std_logic_vector(ADDR-1 downto 0) := (others =>'0');
signal full, empty : std_logic := '0';

 signal     WEA : std_logic_vector(3 downto 0) :=(others=>'0');                      -- 4-bit input: A port write enable
 signal         addra, addrb, dinb, doutb, dina, douta : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) := (others => '0');
 signal         rsta, rstb :std_logic := '0' ; 

 type ram is array (4 downto -2) of std_logic_vector(31 downto 0) ;
 signal mem : ram :=(others=>(others=>'0'));

begin

 ---STACK LOGIC ---

 PUSH : process (clk, push_pop, en, full, empty)
    begin
        if(clk'event and clk='1') then
        WEA <= "0000";          
            if(en='1' and push_pop = '1' and full = '0') then
                mem(to_integer(unsigned(stack_ptr_write))) <= data_in;
                WEA <= "1111";  
                dina <= data_in ;
                ADDRA <= stack_ptr_write;
                stack_ptr_write <= stack_ptr_write + 1; 
            elsif(en='1' and push_pop = '0' and empty = '0') then   
                data_out <= douta ;--
                doutb <= mem(to_integer(unsigned(stack_ptr_write - 1)));
                ADDRA <= stack_ptr_write - 1;
                stack_ptr_write <= stack_ptr_write - 1;
            end if;
        end if;
    end process;

BRAM_SP : BRAM_32_1K_SP
  PORT MAP (
    clka => clk,
    rsta => rsta,
    wea => wea,
    addra => addra,
    dina => dina,
    douta => douta
  );






end Behavioral;
```

Many thanks
Sam

Answer (score 1):

The solution entails several things:

1) You have to explicitly reset the signals with the rst port in every process. Initializing them in their declaration just doesn't cut it.
The process' code with a proper reset and sensitivity list should then look like this:

```
PUSH : process (rst, clk)
begin
    if (rst = '1') then --supposing active-high async. reset
       WEA <= (others => '0');
       ADDRA <= (others => '0');
       dina <= (others => '0');
       data_out <= (others => '0');
       full <= '0';
       empty <= '0';
       stack_ptr_write <= (others => '0');
    elsif(clk'event and clk='1') then
       --your code
```

2) I understand you have several layers/tries of code here in the same place. This is messy to read. I see you are using a "mem" to hold your example (so that WEA, ADDRA, dina, etc are ignorable), but when you get back to BRAM_32_1K_SP remember to check it has 32 bits addresses which, coupled with 32 bits data, mean that you have a 32 * 2**32 bits ram... that is around 128 Gbits, typo I guess.

However, to make a clearer question you should leave only the code pertaining to the memory solution you're having a problem with.

3) your code does include some typos that you should fix, like assigning "doutb" in the process, whereas I guess you wanted to assign data_out instead:

```
data_out <= mem(to_integer(unsigned(stack_ptr_write - 1)));
```

And this is the reason why you don't see what you want at the output.

Comment: In the end myself and my supervisor couldn't work out what was wrong, so instead i am now inferring BRAM (better for design portability as well). And yes I will admit the example I gave was messy and confused after many attempts! But thanks for your time. Sam